# Create a new vector based on unique values in another vector

Tags: r, vector, replace, unique

I have a vector with dates linked to individuals

```
ind  |   date       |   want  
1    | 28.03.1990  -->  87  
1    | 30.05.1990  -->  150  
1    | 09.11.1991  -->    
2    | 14.03.1991  -->      
2    | 01.02.1991  -->    
3    | 10.07.1990  -->
```

I would like to have another vector with daynumber since january 1st (independent of year), as you can see the individual do not have equal number of observations and do not start at the same date.

I have tried replace(), but it won't work as my control vector (e.g. c(1:365)) is not of same lenght as length(observations for a given individual).

The dataset I am working with is quite large (>90 000), so I would preferred to have this done automatically :P

Appreciate any help given :)

Comment: I do not understand your problem... What do you mean with not equal number of observations, what is the start date? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Due to logistics and circumstances the observation start varied and the duration of the observations varied. So they do not have the same start date nor the same length..

Comment: I still do not understand what you are trying to do. You have individuals, right? They observe something(?) at certain dates. That information is already in your vector. Now what will your resulting vector contain? The same information but instead of the dates you want those numbers?

Comment: I meant the observation(period) of each invidual :P

but the resulting vector would contain numbers from 1-365. E.g.
for individual 1 my observation start 03.01.2006 and last until 06.01.2007, i.e. my date vector. I would want my resulting vector to say c(3:365, 1:6). That is recognize each date in date vector and replace it with a number (starting on january 1st) . So it would be same information, only in a different format and I don't care about years, only days within the year.

Did that make it any clearer? :P

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. What programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see where I'm aiming at?

```
> date <- as.Date("28.03.1990", format = "%d.%m.%Y")
> start.date <- as.Date(paste("01.01", format(date, "%Y"), sep = "."), format = "%d.%m.%Y")
> date - start.date
Time difference of 86 days
```

Comment: I saw what you were aiming at ;) I adapted it to my case and it worked perfectly :) A great and mentally loud thank you is sent your way :)